# Is it possible to apply a bezier curve along a mesh?

Tags: mesh

Is it possible to apply a bezier curve, along the surface of a mesh?

Comment: Could you give more details on how the curve would be *applied*? Would this add new geometry or deform existing?

Comment: Is it possible you intended this the other way around, while this is valid, it would make more sense the other way.

Comment: Hi, welcome to blender.SE. Your question isn't very helpful to those of us wanting to answer it. Please add details to the question rather than repeating the title over again.

Comment: We need more details!

Comment: No offense, but it seems pretty straight forward to me. No I don't mean the opposite, I want a curve on a mesh.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier. Select the curve and add the modifier to it, then as its *target*, select the mesh. It will snap the curve to the surface. The settings are pretty intuitive so to get a nice result you can just tweak the settings. Try changing the *Mode* to get a bit more control over how the curve is projected.

[image]