# How can I make curves "stick" to a model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have here a gingerbread man I modeled, and I used a path and [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to create the frosting. But the frosting is hovering over the gingerbread man, so I need to know how to attach the frosting to the gingerbread man. I have already tried using the curve modifier, but it won't give me the results I want.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/433/is-it-possible-to-apply-a-bezier-curve-along-a-mesh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting with  [version 2.78](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Modelling) you can [Draw Freehand Curves](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/editing/draw.html?highlight=draw%20curve).

First create a curve > bezier object in object mode.

Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). You can delete the existing curve segments by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

In the Options tab enable the projection depth to surface, that way the drawn curves will stick to the surface of other objects.

[image]

Then go to the Create tab and select **Draw Curve** to draw a curve directly in the 3D viewport.

[image]

[image]

For more info watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAsUGy7XGOA

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this but after I open Blender there is no "Option" tab, if I switch to Edit mode there is an option tab but no "Curve options". [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/g2YuV)

Comment: Are you using a blender version higher than 7.78? Did you add a curve object? Are you in edit mode? Did you watch the video in the link?

Comment: @MicroMachine edit mode should be for the *curve* object, not for mesh. Add new curve, in Edit mode delete its points and start drawing as above. It's not necessary to delete original one, it might be just more convenient. This is shown in the video

Comment: @cegaton thanks for editing the answer, this helped greatly! Yes I was missing the beginning where you create then delete a curve.

Comment: This is now a few years later. These curves "stick" to the model only when you draw them, but how can you edit them permanently on the surface?