# Measure length of "curve" (or similar) by drawing on mesh

Tags: bezier-curves, units

I know there are a million answers on here about measuring the length of a curve ([like this one, which is pretty much what I want to do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/measurement-of-the-straightened-length-of-a-path)) but I feel like this situation is a tiny bit different.  I have a scene like this:
[image]

Which is the real top of a skull, imported in "real" units.  I'd love to measure the circumference of that hole in the skull and return the length in centimeters, preferably by drawing on it.  I was drawing a curve by eyeball and using the CurveTools addon to get the length, but as you can imagine, its often hard to tell if you're in a correct 3d Plane and actually touching the surface and I often had to manually adjust each point I drew.  What I would love to do is "paint" like so:
[image]
And then have Blender measure the length of that, I imagine by creating a curve where that selection is? I tried separating the mesh by selection and then converting that new chunk into a "curve" and that technically happened, but the new curve couldn't be measured by Curvetools, not sure why.

Blender 2.9 if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found my solution here:

[How can I make curves "stick" to a model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96423/how-can-i-make-curves-stick-to-a-model)

Instead of drawing a selection and then creating a curve from that, you can draw your curve and have it snap to the object as you're drawing.